# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP (4)

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web, servidor

Tenho dois servidores com finalidades diferentes, sendo um um webserver executando apache e php 5.3, e o outro é um servidor de banco de dados MySQL. O primeiro utiliza o banco de dados no segundo 24 horas por dia, 7 dias por semana.

O problema é que recentemente começamos a ter erros algumas vezes ao dia, onde as aplicações PHP retornam a seguinte mensagem de erro para nossos usuários:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_DO_BANCO_DE_DADOS' (4)
```

Temos diversas aplicações PHP em nosso WebServer, sendo que a conexão são executadas de acordo com o framework utilizado. Uma de nossas aplicações (legada) que não faz uso de nenhum framework, e por isto utiliza o nativamente o PHP para se conectar ao MySQL, procede da seguinte maneira:

```
function AbreBD($mysqli = false) {

        global $conexao, $selecao, $conexao_mysqli;

        $servidor = '192.168.101.20:3306';
        $usuarioBD = 'user';
        $senhaBD = 'user';

        $conexao = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuarioBD, $senhaBD);
        $selecao = mysql_select_db("bioextratus", $conexao);

        if ($mysqli) {
            $conexao_mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuarioBD, $senhaBD, "bioextratus");
        }
    }
```

Lembrando que o código acima é para uma aplicação legada, e por isto utiliza ainda o driver mysql ao invés do mysqli. Mesmo em nossas aplicações mais modernas com frameworks o problema também ocorre.

Acredito que o problema seja a configuração do MySQL ou problema de rede, apesar do serviço do MySQL está sempre disponível, assim como a comunicação entre os dois servidores pela rede.

O conteúdo do arquivo my.cnf do MySQL de nosso servidor de banco de dados (sem os comentários):

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = false
open_files_limit        =       102400

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

key_buffer                      = 16M
key_buffer_size                 = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
thread_stack                    = 196K
thread_cache_size               = 8
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP
query_cache_limit               = 64M
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_size                = 256M
max_connections                 = 1024
max_user_connections            = 0
sort_buffer_size                = 2M

join_buffer_size                = 1M
tmp_table_size                  = 64M
max_heap_table_size             = 18M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 12M
```

Comment: Os 2 servidores são de vc ou de um "provider"? da um olhada no log de MySQL para ver se ele detecta problema, ou seja, saber se PHP não pode "falar" com MySQL ou se é Mysql que não entende o que PHP diz. (Nota: não entendo bem a ideia de mysql ao invés de mysqli...)

Answer (score 1):

Bom o problema especificado é amplo demais, podendo ser uma configuração mal realizada no servidor até problemas de instabilidade na rede.

Vou dar um exemplo presente em nosso cotidiano, em situação de teste local raramente encontramos problemas de rede ou falhas/perda na conexão devido a estrutura de nossa rede que pode ser considerada relativamente estável. Já no cliente o cenário muda, nossas aplicações reportam erros por email e não é raro de receber problemas de conexão desse tipo.

Um pouco de referência teórica agora, segundo a documentação oficial do MySQL esse problema ocorre devido:

> The error (2002) Can't connect to ... normally means that there is no
>   MySQL server running on the system or that you are using an incorrect
>   Unix socket file name or TCP/IP port number when trying to connect to
>   the server. You should also check that the TCP/IP port you are using
>   has not been blocked by a firewall or port blocking service.
>
> The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061)
>   indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should
>   check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network
>   connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the
>   one configured on the server.

Traduzindo:

> O erro (2002) Can't connect to ... normalmente significa que não
>   existe nenhum servidor MySQL rodando no sistema ou que você está
>   utilizando um socket Unix ou a porta TCP/IP de forma incorreta. Você
>   deve também verificar se a porta TCP/IP utilizada para conexão não
>   encontra-se bloqueada por um firewall ou outro serviço de bloqueio.

O erro (2003) diz basicamente a mesma coisa.

O que fizemos então para tentar diagnosticar o problema foi efetuar uma espécie de mecanismo de tolerância a falha em nossas aplicações, de forma que, caso ocorra um determinado erro (2002, 2003, entre outros) durante a conexão notificamos que houve uma perda de conexão para o usuário que por um determinado número de tentativas em intervalos de tempo especificados nós realizamos a reconexão.

Ao final nossa quantidade de erros desse tipo diminuiu drasticamente, então fica ai a dica.